# I am making a traffic light with Python turtle and at the end of the sequence I want all the lights to blink yellow

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

This is my code. All I want is for three turtles to move/blink at the same time 
like a broken traffic light.
I can't figure out how to do it.
If you want to see all of my code, let me know by an answer.

```
#flash
speed(20)
#pens
pen1 = Turtle()
pen2 = Turtle()
pen3 = Turtle()
#loop
def loop():

while True:
    pen1.penup()
    pen1.color('yellow')
    pen1.goto(0,90)
    pen1.begin_fill()
    pen1.pendown()
    pen1.circle(40)
    pen1.penup()
    pen1.end_fill()
    pen1.color('black')
    time.sleep(1)
    pen1.begin_fill()
    pen1.pendown()
    pen1.circle(40)
    pen1.penup()
    pen1.end_fill()
    time.sleep(1)
while True:
    pen2.penup()
    pen2.color('yellow')
    pen2.goto(0,-140)
    pen2.begin_fill()
    pen2.pendown()
    pen2.circle(40)
    pen2.penup()
    pen2.end_fill()
    pen2.color('black')
    time.sleep(1)
    pen2.begin_fill()
    pen2.pendown()
    pen2.circle(40)
    pen2.penup()
    pen2.end_fill()
    time.sleep(1)



return loop()
```

Comment: This doesn't look much like python ...

Comment: The while loop will run forever, so I would imagine it's not getting to the second loop...

Comment: so how would i fix it

Comment: If this is really Python the please indent your code correctly so it at least executes. Tabs don't do well on Stack Overflow. Use 4-space indentation please.

Comment: StephenC, ibug This is a python-related question. It's [turtle-graphics](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/turtle-graphics/info) and [turtle — Turtle graphics for Tk](https://docs.python.org/2/library/turtle.html)

Comment: i am sitll learning python

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution based on two key points: first, the turtles aren't used to *draw* the traffic lights, the turtles *are* the traffic lights; second, we use the `ontimer` event in turtle to control the blinking:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

CURSOR_SIZE = 20

def blink():
    for turtle in screen.turtles():
        turtle.fillcolor('yellow' if turtle.fillcolor() == 'black' else 'black')

    screen.ontimer(blink, 1000)

screen = Screen()

pen1 = Turtle(shape='circle')
pen1.shapesize(80 / CURSOR_SIZE)
pen1.color('black', 'yellow')
pen1.penup()
pen1.sety(90)

pen2 = pen1.clone()
pen2.sety(0)

pen3 = pen1.clone()
pen3.sety(-90)

blink()

screen.mainloop()
```